# GLSL syntax highlighting in Visual C# Express 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting, visual-c#-express-2010

On a friends version of visual studio, we saw to our surprise that a text file with the extention .frag or .vert has GLSL syntax highlighting. Is this a new feature? How can I get it in my version which is also 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [NShader](http://nshader.codeplex.com/) extension for that.

Comment: Oh sweet, I didn't know it was an extension! I thought that he might've had a different version of Visual C#

Comment: VS Express editions are not supported as they don't allow community addins.